# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pybarcode

Tags: gnu

I am trying to install GNU Health 3.4.1, I have tried with several S.O of linux but the problem persists.
Issue:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pybarcode (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pybarcode.

Help!!

Answer (score 1):

To install pyBarcode dependency of GNU Health open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install python3-pip  
python3 -m pip install --user pyBarcode
```

<sub>To install gnuhealth-3.4.1.tar.gz: [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/)</sub>

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# sudo pip3 install pyBarcode Collecting pyBarcode Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyBarcode (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pyBarcode

The problem continues...

Answer (score 0):

The GNU Health installer (gnuhealth-setup) has been updated to 3.4.1. 
It basically fixes an issue due to the removal of the the pybarcode library from pypi (https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?55942) 
We have also updated the documentation to always download the latest installer as the first step (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GNU_Health/Installation#Downloading_and_Installing_GNU_Health) 
This applies for new installations / migrations.

Cite: http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=9399